# Asymptotic equivalence-like relation

Tags: asymptotics, terminology

> Let $f, g: \mathbb R\to (0,\infty)$ such that $\cfrac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ is
>   bounded both from below and above for all $x\in\mathbb R$.

Is there any name for this relation? (Like if $\cfrac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ would converge to 1 as $x\to\infty$, one would say that they are asymptotically equivalent.)

Comment: How is it asymptotic if you require it's true for all $x\in \mathbb R$ ?

Comment: It isn't, but that was what it reminded me of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably looking for the big-theta notation
$$\forall x_0,\ f(x)=\Theta(g(x))\ x\to x_0$$
matches exactly with your definition